# Finding the upper bound of a complex contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that 
$$
\left\lvert\int_\gamma \frac{\cos(z)}z \,dz\right\rvert \le 2\pi e
$$ 
if $\gamma$ is a path that traces the unit circle once.

The book recommends that I show that $\lvert \cos(z) \rvert \le e$ if $\lvert z \rvert = 1$ to help prove this. I know that if $\lvert f(z) \rvert \le M$ for all $z \in \gamma (I)$ then 
$$
\left\lvert \int_\gamma f(z) \,dz \right\rvert \le M\ell (\gamma),
$$ where $\ell (\gamma)$ is the length of the path, which in this case is $2\pi$. So I can see why I would need to show $\lvert cos(z) \rvert \le e$ if $\lvert z \rvert = 1$ to prove the inequality, but I am not sure where to go from here to show that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the series expansion of $\cos$ we get for $|z|=1$:

$$| \cos z| \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)!} \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=e.$$

Answer (score 4):

The exponential function satisfies the inequality $\vert e^z \vert \leq e^{\vert z \vert}$. We have
$$\cos(z) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}),$$
thus
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\vert \cos(z) \vert &\leq \frac{1}{2}( \vert e^{iz} \vert + \vert e^{-iz} \vert) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{\vert z \vert} + e^{\vert z \vert}) \\
&= e^{\vert z \vert}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So when $\vert z \vert = 1$ we have $\vert \cos(z) \vert \leq e$.

Answer (score 1):

$|\cos z|=|\frac {e^{iz}+e^{-z}} 2| \leq \frac {e+e} 2=e$ because $|e^{z}| \leq e^{|z|}$.